# Reactjs frontend gets error when backend runs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm using React Js as frontend and node express as backend. When I start the my frontend using `npm start` it runs without errors but when I start my backend too then it throws this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` and I could not find any solution for this.

Here's the code where the error is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ApiService from "../../service/ApiService";
import SearchField from "./SearchField";

class ListModuleComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            modules: [],
            message: null
        }
        this.deleteModule = this.deleteModule.bind(this);
        this.editModule = this.editModule.bind(this);
        this.addModule = this.addModule.bind(this);
        this.reloadModuleList = this.reloadModuleList.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.reloadModuleList();
    }

    reloadModuleList() {
        ApiService.fetchModules()
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({ modules: res.data.result })
            });
    }

    deleteModule(moduleId) {
        ApiService.deleteModule(moduleId)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({ message: 'Delete successful.' });
                this.setState({ modules: this.state.modules.filter(module => module.id !== moduleId) });
            })

    }

    editModule(id) {
        window.localStorage.setItem("moduleId", id);
        this.props.history.push('/edit-module');
    }

    addModule() {
        window.localStorage.removeItem("moduleId");
        this.props.history.push('/add-module');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2 className="text-center">Modul data</h2>
                <button className="btn btn-danger" style={{ width: '100px' }} onClick={() => this.addModule()}>Add</button>
                <SearchField />
                <table className="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th className="hidden">Id</th>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            {/* <th>Key</th> */}
                            <th>Default value</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>State</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {
                            this.state.modules.map( // Error throws on this line //
                                module =>
                                    <tr key={module.id}>
                                        <td>{module.moduleName}</td>
                                        <td>{module.moduleDefaultValue}</td>
                                        <td>{module.description}</td>
                                        <td>{module.isActive}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={() => this.deleteModule(module.id)}> Delete</button>
                                            <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={() => this.editModule(module.id)} style={{ marginLeft: '20px' }}>Edit</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                            )
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default ListModuleComponent;
```

So the error only show up if my backend starts and I don't know if it is caused by backend or frontend, only see the error for the React frontend side. I can provide more code if needed.

Comment: Are you sure that `res.data.result` returns an actual array? My guess is that this one returns `undefined` instead.

Comment: you have to log out your api responses before you call set state like `this.setState({ modules: res.data.result })` because `res.data.result` is undefined so you can either conditionally set it to that or default it to an empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res.result.data` is most likely `undefined`. You could solve this in 2 ways:

## 1. Prevent undefined in your state.

You could set your state to an empty array in case `res.result.data` is `undefined` like so:

```
this.setState({ modules: res.data.result || [] });
```

This will make sure your state always contains an array even if the backend provides no data.

---

## 2. Do a null-check before rendering your data.

Check if your `this.state.modules` holds a value before rendering your content.

```
<div>
  {this.state.modules && this.state.modules.map(module => {
    // Code
  }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this was the problem, that ```res.result.data``` was ```undefined```

Comment: I would perhaps be more precise with a null check, as he is referring to a very specific array functionality afterwards. Thus I would rather check for `instanceof Array` otherwise you could call an undefined function again.

Answer (score 1):

The default state for modules is an array, this means that mapping over it is okay, so if it doesnt fetch any data then the component will render just fine.

```
this.state = {
        modules: [],
        message: null
    }
```

When the backend has been started the reload modules method is setting the modules to be **res.data.result**

The error is Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

Because of this I think res.data.result is undefined.

to fix this check what res is and make sure the thing you are setting in state is the array of data

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a null check would fix the obvious problems here.

```
{
  this.state.modules instanceof Array && this.state.modules.map(
    module => { /*...*/ }
  )
}
```

Nevertheless, I strongly assume that the backend has already delivered the data correctly. Also your code has an assumption that the array is always there and I cannot find a place where it has been deleted/false initialized. So I Just assume that the backend returns you an undefined/null value, which would also be covered by this check. So maybe investigate your backend whether it returns a null value.